# A chain of measurable sets has union measurable

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Consider a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and let $I$ be an arbitrary index set.

Is the following true?

> If $\left( A_i \right)_{i \in I}$ is a chain in $\mathcal{F}$ – that is, $\forall i \in I$, $A_i \in \mathcal{F}$ and for all $i, j \in I$, we have $A_i \subseteq A_j$ or $A_j \subseteq A_i$  – then $$\displaystyle \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \in \mathcal{F}.$$

Answer (score 6):

This isn't true in general (assuming the axiom of choice).

Let $\kappa$ be the least cardinal of a non-measurable set of reals; let $f$ map $\kappa$ 1-1 onto such a non-measurable set.

Then $\{f\!"\!\alpha \mid \alpha\lt\kappa\}$ (where $f\!"\!\alpha$ denotes the range of $f$ on $\alpha)$ is a chain of measurable sets whose union is not measurable.

To see that the axiom of choice needs to be used in some way, at least for the case of Lebesgue measure on the reals, note that it's consistent with ZF that every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Even if you have a non-measurable set, I guess you need AC again in order to prove that your mon-measurable set is the union of a chain of sets of smaller cardinality?

Comment: You need to know that there's a non-measurable set that's well-orderable for this argument to work. Once you have that, you can get a function $f$ and a chain as I indicated, and it all works.  I haven't thought about what happens if AC fails in such a way that there are non-measurable sets but none of them are well-orderable. (Nor have I thought about measurable spaces in general, just the reals under Lebesgue measure.)

Answer (score 5):

No. Consider Lebesgue measure on the real line. Let $\kappa$ be the minimum cardinality of a non-measurable set, and let $A$ be a non-measurable set of cardinality $\kappa.$ Then $A$ is the union of a chain of sets of cardinality less than $\kappa,$ which are of course measurable sets.

Comment: Why "of course?"

Comment: Because $\kappa$ was defined to be the ***minimum*** cardinality of a non-measurable set, it follows that any set of cardinality less than $\kappa$ must be measurable.

Comment: Sure, but how do you know that the set can be formed as the union of sets with smaller cardinality?

Comment: My "of course" referred to the fact that the smaller sets were measurable, not to the fact that $A$ is the union of a chain of smaller sets. That's true for any infinite set, as a consequence of the well-ordering theorem. First, $A$ can be well-ordered. Second, if it can be well-ordered, then it can be well-ordered so that every proper initial segment has strictly smaller cardinality than $A.$ The initial segments are (of course!) nested, and finally, since $A$ is infinite, their union is equal to $A.$

Answer (score 1):

Within the known axioms of set theory you cannot disprove that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1.$ Recall that $\aleph_1$ is defined as the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals and $2^{\aleph_0}$ is the cardinality of $[0,1]$.

Let $A$ be any non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$.  Suppose $|[0,1]| = 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$.  Since $A$ must be uncountable and since no cardinality lies between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$ (that much is provable within conventional set theory), we have $|A|=\aleph_1$, so
$$
A = \{ a_i : i \text{ is a countable ordinal} \},
$$
for some indexing $i\mapsto a_i$.  Then let
$$
A_i = \{ a_j : j \le i\}.
$$
Then for each $i$, the set $A_i$ is countable, hence measurable, but
$$
\bigcup_i A_i = A
$$
is not measurable.

Since you can't disprove that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1,$ you can't prove that your proposed union must be measurable.

Comment: The continuum hypothesis is not provable within conventional set theory.

Comment: This just shows that it can't be proven in ZFC. In fact, it's false in ZFC, as you can see from my answer and @bof's answer.